# How does Workbox decide if a route matches a request?

Tags: workbox

A common pattern in Workbox is to cache Google resources with a StaleWhileRevalidate strategy:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        /.*(?:googleapis)\.com/,
        new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
            cacheName: 'googleapis',
        })
);
```

I like to understand why the regular expression used in the example above matches requests for any sub-resources on googleapis.com altough the regular expresion itself only matches the domain,  subdomain and top level domain part of the URI. So Workbox seems to fire the handler for both complete matches and for partial matches. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying class that's being used is [`RegExpRoute`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing.RegExpRoute), and there is [expanded documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#how_to_register_a_regular_expression_route) explaining some of the behavior.

You're correct that when using `RegExpRoute`, the route will trigger if the `RegExp` matches the URL in question. If the `RegExp` does not include `^` and `$` or anything else that would anchor it to the start or end of a string, then partial matches will also trigger it.

This is honestly a little confusing, and a while ago [we went through the documentation](https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/pull/8680) and changed almost all of the routing examples to use the [`matchCallback`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing#~matchCallback) syntax instead, with checks made against the `url` or `request` parameters.

The rough equivalent, in (arguably) a clearer syntax, to what you shared above would be

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.origin.endsWith('googleapis.com'),
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'googleapis',
  })
);
```